# Copy assignment and copy constructor(difference in code C++)

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I don't understand some syntax in C++ Copy assignment and copy constructor:

**Copy constructor:**

```
vector::vector(const vector& arg)
// allocate elements, then initialize them by copying
    :sz{arg.sz}, elem{new double[arg.sz]}
{
    copy(arg,arg+sz,elem);    // std::copy(); see §B.5.2
}
```

[Link to original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj6js.png)

**Copy assingment:**

```
class vector {
    int sz;
    double* elem;
public:
    vector& operator=(const vector&);    // copy assignment
    //...
};

vector& vector::operator=(const vector& a)
    // make this vector a copy of a
{
    double* p = new double[a.sz];       // allocate new space
    copy(a.elem,a.elem+a.sz,elem);      // copy elements
    delete[] elem;                      // deallocate old space
    elem = p;                           // now we can reset elem
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;                       // return a self-reference (see §17.10)
}
```

[Link to original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TY77.png)

What I don't understand is:

why in copy constructor we copy elements like this:

`copy(arg,arg + sz,elem)`, but in copy assingment like this:`copy(a.elem,a.elem + a.sz,elem)`?

Can you explain me this difference?

Comment: `copy(arg,arg + sz,elem)` makes little sense. Where is the code from?

Comment: Please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48100041/edit) the code as code, not as images.

Comment: If this code is copied from a book, check the list of corrections: `copy(arg,arg + sz,elem)` is a typo.

Comment: @Angew this is code from Stroustrup: Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++. 

How should I correct it?

Comment: Can you confirm what edition?

Comment: @UKMonkey second edition

Comment: @Angew should it be corrected like this: copy(arg.elem,arg.elem+ a.sz,elem)?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the name of the argument and the type passed to `std:: copy`.

`std:: copy` is a templated function; therefore it changes the type of the arguments (double, int, string, ...)

What you need to worry about is of the parameter description (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
```

- first, last -     the range of elements to copy
- d_first -     the beginning of the destination range.